# JQuery DateTimePicker - Dates before 1970 are giving negatives

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

My application needs a DOB calendar that allows users to enter birth dates from the year 1900.
I'm using Jquery UI DateTimePicker add-on to that, but when we select a date before **epoch** (Jan 1st 1970), its returning a negative timestamp. How do I handle this?

I get that JavaScript date objects work based on epoch. Help me handling the negatives so that I can allow users who born before 1970 to access my site. :)

Comment: Why is a negative timestamp a problem?

Comment: @MichaelLiu can save the negative timestamp, but when I try to display it or set to datepicker, all is not well.
I do this way,
'$('.editDOB').datePickerVal(data.dob);'

which didnt work, because of -ve timestamp.

Comment: What is `datePickerVal`? A Google search didn't return much.